# creating a request to replace curl -XDelete - Python

Tags: python, http, post, curl, python-requests

I'm executing the following `cURL` command to clean an Elastic Search index:

```
curl -s -XDELETE "http://<server>/<server_index>/<index>/_query" -d '{
    "query":{"match_all":{}}}
}'
```

However, I don't to execute a shell script or a `subprocess` command. Instead, I want to rely on [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to achieve this:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://<server>/<server_index>/<index>/_query')
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent requests code should be something like:

```
data = {"query": {"match_all": {}}}

import requests

r = requests.delete("http://<server>/<server_index>/<index>/_query", data=data)
```